# Consistent---but Automatic---Color Choices in Plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, pie-chart

I'm creating pie charts using plotly in R.

Currently, plotly automatically assigns colors by the size of the slice. Typically, blue is the largest, then orange, etc.

I'd like to assign colors in a way that is more consistent, so that **pie charts of different columns assign the same color to the same row.** However, I don't know what sort of data frame this script will be running on, so need to do so automatically (Say assigning colors by alphabetical order)

Heres my current code:

```
p = plot_ly(df, labels = ~Group, values = ~x, type = 'pie', textinfo = 'none')
```

Thanks!